# FaceTime & iMessage auth troubleshooting

Tags: icloud, apple-id, facetime

I have created a separate user for my GF on my mac (macos Catalina 10.15.4) but I cannot log into  FaceTime and iMessage. FaceTime shows "this account has no reachable addresses" error, but account is connected to appleid and works on her iphone. iMessage just shows incorrect login or password. I tried re-login with my credits and it works fine. My GF has such troubles with FT and IMsg on her phone about year ago, but after updating on 12 ios this problem disappeared.

It seems like something wrong with her AppleID, her Icloud profile can't load her avatar on MacOS and sometimes there are troubles with updating info, it doesn't save data.

Comment: Are you able to login successfully with her Apple ID to https://appleid.apple.com/ (in a desktop web browser)?

Comment: yes, I'm able to do that

Comment: @AlexanderBondarenko Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have resolved this issue, will write it as official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. It turned out that my GF's apple id was blocked on one of apple servers. I have got in touch with apple support and they resolved my issue. If you are living in the country with no apple id support, go to apple support website, select you're living in US and find any service like itunes issues or something like that with chat support. Connect to chat and describe your problem, say you are from the country with no apply support (it's important). As usual they will connect you with tech specialist who is responsible for all these issues.